# How to connect to AWS OpenSearch Service in Java using Apache HttpClient 5 Transport or Apache RestClient Transport

Tags: java, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am using AWS SDK version 1, so using `AwsSdk2Transport` to setup `OpenSearchClient` is out of the option. Also, Java high-level REST client is getting deprecated. How can I connect to AWS OpenSearch cluster without using `AwsSdk2Transport` and Java high-level REST client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is here: https://forum.opensearch.org/t/how-to-connect-to-aws-opensearch-service-without-using-awssdk2transport/14657/1.
You can connect to AWS OpenSearch Service using both Apache HttpClient 5 Transport and RestClient Transport.